# Energy transformation for pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The equation of motion of a mass on a pendulum is

$$ \ddot x + \omega^2\sin x = 0 $$

where $t$ = time and $x$ = inclination from the vertical.

According to my book, it is possible to re-write $ \ddot x $ in terms of $ \dot x $ and $ x $ by using:

$$ 
\begin{align} 
\ddot x & = \frac{d \dot x}{dt} \\
& = \frac{d \dot x}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} \\
& =  \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\dot x^2\right)
\end{align}$$

I don't understand where the $ \frac{1}{2} $ comes from. It seems to me that since $\dot x = \frac{dx}{dt}$ we should end up with

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \dot x \frac{dx}{dt} \right) = \frac{d}{dx} (\dot x \dot x) = \frac{d}{dx} (\dot x^2) $$

Can anyone tell me where the $1/2$ comes from? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to use this to solve?

Comment: Such a lack of rigor in your book! Very bad. But it works fine after all.

Comment: @Winther I'm trying to understand the derivation of the phase-diagram for the pendulum equation.

Answer (score 3):

let assume that $$\dot x(t)=f(x(t)) $$

You agree that $$\ddot x(t)=\frac{df(x(t))}{dt}=f'(x(t))\dot x(t) $$

In the other hand ,

$y(t)=\frac{1}{2}f(x(t))^2$ has for derivative with respect to x

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}*2*f(x(t))*f'(x(t))$$

Answer (score 2):

Up to the lack of rigor in your book, note that
$$ 
\frac{d \dot x}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d \dot x}{dx} \dot x=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}\dot x^2\right),
$$
thinking of $\dot x$ as $\dot x=\dot x(x)$ (**the new variable being $x$**).

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the product rule when looking at this equation:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(u*v) = v*\frac{du}{dx} + u*\frac{dv}{dx}\\
$$
Since, in this case, $u = v$ you will obtain the following equation:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2) =\frac{1}{2}*2\dot{x}*\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx} =\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}
$$